# Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration' while importing log4j2.xml file in spring

Tags: spring, log4j2

I am getting the exception as -

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' WARN  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document from class path resource [log4j2.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 31; Element type "Configuration" must be declared.
    ERROR Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document from class path resource [log4j2.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 31; Element type "Configuration" must be declared.
```

Below is the Spring annotation configuration -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.*")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@ImportResource("classpath:log4j2.xml")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        ...
}
```

Below is the log4j2 xml configuration file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configuration>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">C:/logs/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
            ...
   </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        ...
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

How to get rid of this error ? Is there any mistake while importing the file into the application ? Want to enable log4j2 configuration into the project. Will the xml file be automatically understood by spring or need to write some class for it ? The maven pom file does not include sax dependency. Is that a problem ?

Comment: I think that you do not need "@ImportResource("classpath:log4j2.xml")" and "<!DOCTYPE Configuration>". Please remove this lines and try again.

Comment: @TobiasOtto changes made as mentioned but logs are not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "@ImportResource("classpath:log4j2.xml")" is the problem. Please remove this line and try again.

With @ImportResource you could add some Spring-XML-Configurations. This is not for Log4J2-Configuration.

The Log4J2-Framework will search for this resources (log4j2.xml) in the classpath. Please look at: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

You have to enable the logging-framework with Spring. Please see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: Then how to import log4j2 xml file ? Without this xml file logs will not be generated. I want to configure with xml file only.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks, everyone for you answers. Was problem in the configuration file. After an hour of brainstorming I figured it out. Just changed the configuration file code and it is working fine.